# how to config yii2 urlManager rules with aliases and $_GET parameter

Tags: php, url-routing, yii2

for my current (advanced) yii2-based project i just need one controller (SiteController). So there is no need to show it in the url. Thats why i added this rule to the frontend config:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'rules' => array(
        '<alias:product|contact|about>' => 'site/<alias>',
    ),
```

This is working fine and *localhost/product* points to *localhost/site/product*.

Of course, i activated prettyUrl and added this default rules to the common config:

```
 'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\w+>' => '<controller>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
```

Now i want to access a GET parameter like this: *localhost/product/productname*. But i get the error:

> Unable to resolve the request "product"

but *localhost/site/product/productname* is working properly...
The "productname" should be $_GET['id']. What do i have to change to make this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your rules should be before the default ones, and you need 2 rules, e.g. :

```
'rules' => array(
    '<alias:contact|about>' => 'site/<alias>',
    '<alias:product>/<id:\w+>' => 'site/<alias>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\w+>' => '<controller>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
),
```

Comment: Here what is w+?

Comment: @YasarArafath  **`\w` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])**

Answer (score -2):

Just define var in your action, for example `public function actionProduct($id)` and `$id` been is `$_GET['id']`